# Altering pytorch resnet head from sigmoid to Softmax

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm new to pytorch. I wrote the below code to do predication using Resnet with Sigmoid for binary classification. I just need to change it to softmax because I might have more than 2 classes.

I understood that pytorch, unlike, Keras, the softmax is in the ***CrossEntropyLoss***. So I'm not sure how could I change the top layer to make the model uses softmax:

```
model =  torchvision.models.resnet50(pretrained=False)


model.fc = torch.nn.Sequential(
    torch.nn.Linear(
        in_features=2048,
        out_features=1
    ) ,   torch.nn.Sigmoid()
)


model = model.cpu()
```

and later:

```
lossFunc=torch.nn.BCELoss(class_weights)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
model.fc[1] = torch.nn.Softmax(10)
```

where 10 are the number of classes, you can put value based on your needs.